# Laravel routes with wildcards always 404

Tags: routes, wildcard, laravel

I'm just starting to use Laravel, and I quite like the idea of the routing, but any route I create that has a wildcard falls back to the Laravel 404 route.

Here's my routes file:

```
# This loads fine
Route::get('hello', function(){
   return 'Hello!';
});

# This gives me a 404
Route::get('hello/(:any)', function ($name) {
    return "Welcome, $name.";
});

Route::get( array('/'), function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});

Event::listen('404', function()
{
    return Response::error('404');
});

Event::listen('500', function()
{
    return Response::error('500');
});
```

I've also tried with `any` to no avail.

```
Route::any('hello/(:any)', function ($name) {
    return "Sup, $name?";
});
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting 404s?

**Edit:**
I guess it's something spotty with my PHP config and not handling the aliases for the classes properly or something. Adding in a helper class that maps the aliases to classes works most of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any other new people to Laravel, this is how you set up a route with an optional parameter.

```
Route::get('hello/(:any?)', function ($name = 'default') {
    return "Welcome, $name.";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your Apache rewrite module enabled?
I've tried your first route on my Laravel installation and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, I get the 404 from Laravel, not Apache. I think it's just because I was silly and didn't understand the route. It should have been `(:any?)` with a default option passed to the anonymous function. Thank you for taking a look!